# Count Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var permalink = 'http://www.google.com';


var getTwitterCount = function () {
    $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + permalink + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        var twitterShares = data.count;
        $('.fa-twitter .share-count').text(twitterShares);
    });
};
getTwitterCount();
var getFacebookCount = function () {
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + permalink + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        var facebookShares = data[permalink].shares;
        $('.fa-facebook .share-count').text(facebookShares);
    });
};
getFacebookCount();
var getPinterestCount = function () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=' + permalink + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        var pinterestShares = data.count;
        $('.fa-pinterest .share-count').text(pinterestShares);
    });
};
getPinterestCount();


<a class="fa fa-facebook" href="" ><span class="share-count">2</span></a>
<a class="fa fa-twitter" href="" ><span class="share-count">8</span></a>
<a class="fa fa-pinterest" href="" ><span class="share-count">5</span></a>
```

The actual problem is this when I am trying to get total count of the post like this

```
var totalcount =$('.share-count')[0].innerHTML + $('.share-count')[1].innerHTML + $('.share-count')[2].innerHTML;
```

it shows totalcount =285 instead of 15 count

Also tried `parseFloat($('.share-count')[0].innerHTML)` but its giving an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Is there any way to get the total count by using for loop or any other method help me

Comment: Where is the JavaScript put in your HTML? Before or after the HTML?

Comment: Can you try replacing .innerHTML with .innerText, and then doing a parseInt instead of a parseFloat?

Comment: @DavidLi it stlill giving me error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined"

Comment: OHHH i didn't realize you were using a jquery object. The functions for a jquery object for html and text are html() and text(), not innerHTML and innerText. Try `($'.share-count')[0].text()`

Comment: Tried `var totalcount = parseInt( $('.share-count')[0].innerHTML ) + 
    parseInt( $('.share-count')[1].innerHTML ) + 
    parseInt( $('.share-count')[2].innerHTML );` and it works fine.

Comment: @DavidLi  use a per your advice $('.share-count').text() but result giving 285 instead of 15

Comment: @PeterKA Not working

Comment: Try surrounding ask of that code in this: `$(function(){ your code here });`

Comment: Mine is working and returning 15 as well... Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Try this as well `var totalcount = parseInt( $('.share-count')[0].innerText ) + parseInt( $('.share-count')[1].innerText ) + parseInt( $('.share-count')[2].innerText);`

Comment: I SUDDENLY UNDERSTAND WHY YOU ARE SEEING 285. That is your 3 counts. 2. 8. 5. These are showing up in your DOM. To see totalcount variable, log it or alert it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalcount = parseInt($('.share-count:eq(0)').text()) + 
parseInt($('.share-count:eq(1)').text()) +
parseInt($('.share-count:eq(2)').text())
```

or generic:

```
var totalcount = $('.share-count')
  .map(function(i,e){ // convert array of elements to array of ints
    return parseInt($(e).text());
  }) 
  .toArray()
  .reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) { // calculate sum of array
    return previousValue + currentValue
  }, 0)
```